# Scroll distance - Accessibility Service ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD?

Tags: android, scroll, action, accessibility

How can I get the scroll distance that had been scrolled after performing ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD in a Accessibility Service? Normally the scroll distance would be one full length of the ScrollView which has been scrolled, but if the content in the ScrollView is shorter than the full length the amount that will be scrolled is also shorter. How can I get this distance?

Would be really helpful if someone can point me in the right direction :)

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hi. Did you find something about it?

Comment: Sadly not. Nothing that works perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

You can call event.getScrollX() and event.getScrollY(), to know the scroll distance in X and Y directions respectively